# Using qsort() from stdlib.c to sort an array of strings in C according to the 3rd letter in each *char

Tags: c, arrays, string, qsort

I have an array of char* like this

```
aob3l
gou5!
oib1k
llp6d
```

with every 3rd index a number.

I want to use qsort() to sort that list according to those numbers.

A sorted list would look like this

```
oib1k
aob3l
gou5!
llp6d
```

This is how I'm trying to implement it.

```
qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof(char), compare_at3);
```

My `compare_at3` function looks like this

```
int compare_at3(const void* a, const void* b){
    static int k = 1;
    const char *ia = a;
    const char *ib = b;

    printf("In compare_at3 %d iter\n", k++);

    return ((ia[3] - '0') - (ib[3] - '0'));
}
```

And my question is,

what am I doing wrong to get SIGSEGV segfault errors?

My best guess is that this line `const char *ia = a;` isn't doing what I think it's doing.

I'm using `*` in `*ia` so I can subscript `int` as its index but maybe `*ia` isn't the `char*` like `aob3l`.

EDIT1: Sorry, I didn't mention what exactly `string_mix` is.

It's a 2D array of those strings in the question defined like

`char* string_mix[MAX_NO_OF_STRINGS]`

```
char s1_formatted[strlen(s1)];
char s2_formatted[strlen(s2)];
formatted(s1, s1_formatted);
formatted(s2, s2_formatted);

char s1_s[26][MAX_LEN_A];
char s2_s[26][MAX_LEN_B];

for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    sprintf(s1_s[ch - 'a'], "%c%d%s", ch, s1_n[ch - 'a'], t_stringer1[ch - 'l']);
    sprintf(s2_s[ch - 'a'], "%c%d%s", ch, s2_n[ch - 'a'], fs_stringer1[ch - 'o')]);
}

char* string_mix[MAX_NO_OF_STRINGS];

int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    if(s1_s[i][3] - '0' != 0){
        string_mix[k] = s1_s[i];
        k++;
    }
    else if(s2_s[i][3] - '0' != 0){
        string_mix[k] = s2_s[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `const char *ia = a;` to  `const char *ia = (char *)a;`

Comment: The problem is not in your function.   It will be in the call `qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof(char), compare_at3)`.   If `string_mix` is an array of `char *` and `k-1` is equal to the number of elements in `string_mix`, then the call will need to be `qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof(char *), compare_at3)`  (note the additional `*` in the operand of `sizeof`).      However, if `string_mix` or `k-1` are something else (you haven't specified), all bets are off.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` looks fishy, please post a [MCVE]. There is not enough information, so there is no reliable way to answer this question.

Comment: if you have array with 20 characters, call `qsort(string_mix, 4, 5, compare_at3);`, it should work. You want to sort 4 elements when each one has 5 bytes length.

Comment: Since you don't show the variable declarations, nobody can answer the question. What is `k`? Why do you do implicit casts to size_t, are you trying to use a C++ compiler? Your qsort is definitely wrong: each item in your list is either an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`, not a single `char`. Using a static variable in the compare function seems mighty fishy.

Comment: @Lundin: The static object in the comparison function is just for debugging. It is not used in evaluating the comparison, just for printing a statement to help the OP trace execution. It can be disregarded.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So you say, but the OP seems to name every variable in their program `k`...

Comment: @Lundin K in the compare function is just there for debugging. The implicit casting is just a habit.

Comment: @MichaelWalz `string_mix` is a 2D array consisting of those strings in the question. Defined like `char* string_mix[MAX_NO_OF_STRINGS]`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Done! Sorry about that.

Comment: @dis.obs as already requested you should post a [MCVE].

Comment: Please post a [mcve] what you posted is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string_mix` is an array of pointers - each array element is a pointer.  `qsort()` calls need to pass the size of the element. [@Klas Lindbäck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302209/2410359)

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

char* string_mix[MAX_NO_OF_STRINGS];

// qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof(char), compare_at3);

// I suppose k-1 represents the count of elements used 
size_t number_of_elements = k - 1;

qsort(string_mix, number_of_elements, sizeof string_mix[0], compare_at3);
```

---

> what am I doing wrong to get SIGSEGV segfault errors?

Wrong type assumed in compare function.

The compare function receives 2 pointers.  Each is a pointer to an element of the array.  In OP's case this is a pointer to a pointer.

```
int compare_at3(const void* a, const void* b){
  static int k = 1;
  printf("In compare_at3 %d iter\n", k++);

  // const char *ia = a;
  const char **ia = (const char **) a;
  const char **ib = (const char **) b;

  const char *sa = *ia;
  const char *sb = *ib;

  // Code could insure sa, sb are long enough
  if (sa[0] == '\0' || sa[1] == '\0' || sa[2] == '\0') Handle_OddCase();
  if (sb[0] == '\0' || sb[1] == '\0' || sb[2] == '\0') Handle_OddCase();

  // The classic compare indium is below, it never overflows.
  return (sa[3] > sb[3]) - (sa[3] < sb[3]);
}
```

---

Note: Concerning OP comment "It's a 2D array of those strings in the question defined like".  `string_mix` is better described as a 1D array of pointers.

```
char* string_mix[MAX_NO_OF_STRINGS];
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `qsort` is incorrect. The third parameter should be the size of each element. A correct call could be:

```
qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof *string_mix, compare_at3);
```

or, if you prefer, and assuming `string_mix` is an array of `char*`:

```
qsort(string_mix, (size_t) (k - 1), sizeof (char*), compare_at3);
```

Comment: We don't really know what `string_mix` is, so not sure if this is the right answer.

Comment: @ryyker we don't know what `string_mix` is, the OP didn't bother to tell us, therefore using `sizeof (char*)` might or might not be the thing to use. In other words we don't know if he wants to sort pointers to strings or just strings.

Comment: This is why we shouldn't answer the question in the first place - it can't be answered since not enough information was provided. Instead of guessing, ask the OP for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

You convert a void pointer to a char pointer and access index 3 without knowing anything about the memory, the char pointer is pointing to inside the function. This is bad style and most probably the reason for your SIGSEGV, because you cannot access ia[3].

Furthermore, you say, you want to sort according to the 3rd letter... this would be ia[2], if ia were the correct pointer to the char array.

Please post your code... how did you create the array of char*?

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. Yes, you need 50 points of reputation to be able to comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz -  Yes, but it is a decent comment, and yes, answerer does need points for any other interaction

Comment: Pointer type in the compare function is most probably not causing the problem. As the function shall compare strings, it is a valid assumption that accessing the pointers via a `char*` does not cause problems. Problem is that swapping the elements of the array only swaps 1 byte instead of a pointer.

Comment: The number (non-ascii character) is at index [3], not [2]. Text of the question is a bit unclear, while the provided data shows what is desired

Comment: The `qsort` interface **requires** that the comparison routines accept `const void *`, and they must cast them to pointers to the actual type. This is not bad style because it is not style; it is a requirement of C. It may be deficient in some regards compared to facilities available in more modern language, but that is a legacy burden, and it is not the OP’s responsibility and has no relevance to the question.

Comment: Of course they know about the memory, they pass an array of a certain format to qsort. It is not bad style, since qsort expects a function with two `const void*`, there's no way around it. Do you even know how qsort works?

Comment: Thanks for voting me down becuase I wanted to help.